# Matchpairs not working?

Tags: match

I'd like to match pairs in nvim and have the following code:

```
vim.opt.matchpairs:append("❪:❫")
vim.opt.matchpairs:append("⟮:⟯")
vim.opt.matchpairs:append("❨:❩")
```

However, typing `%` does not match the pairs. What am I missing?

Comment: Check if it really was added to the matchpairs option: `:set matchpairs?` . Also, what's wrong with `set matchpairs+=❪:❫,⟮:⟯,❨:❩` ?

Comment: I use init.lua and have tried `vim.opt.matchpairs:append("❪:❫,⟮:⟯,❨:❩")` as well. The response of `:set matchpairs?` is `matchpairs=(:),{:},[:],❪:❫,⟮:⟯,❨:❩`.

Comment: well, then I don't know why it wouldn't work